# Will we be able to use dapps on smartphones?

Tags: dapps, mobile-wallet

I know currently there is no chance to use Dapps on mobile. Are there any upcoming projects to solve this issue?
I think this is most necessary part of Dapps. Without mobile support there is no way.

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/18708/4108)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a project like [Trust Wallet](https://trustwalletapp.com) that's working on providing a mobile experience for dApps on Ethereum blockchain. It's available both on iOS and Android.

As a based you have a wallet for handling key securely locally on the phone, since you need to have a private key in order to communicate with a blockchain.

Trust has a Browser feature which is injecting JavaScript web3 provider to handle sign transaction and messages.

To learn how this being implemented you can check out source code: https://github.com/TrustWallet/trust-wallet-ios

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It means that in the near future Dapps will be massively adopted by the users.

Comment: @George it will take some time but I'm very confident about dApps taking over in the next few years.

Answer (score 1):

I fully agree that this is desperately neede. There is the status.im mobile browser which is currently in early alpha. There are no usable mobile libraries just yet as also discussed [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4556/ethereum-library-for-ios-android/6611#6611). I am sure this will change at some point but for now I think you're left with a range of hacks:

- compile geth with light mode for mobile (never tried, sounds involved)
- run nodeJS in background of app (e.g. in web view) and use some of the javascript libraries (ugly and additional resource constraints)
- use the web3.js library and connect to a node remotely (security and centralisation risks)
- use status.im which is very early alpha but I think will be like mist at some point
- use web based solutions that also work relatively well on mobile (myetherwallet.com)