# Why no dapps in the Google Play Store? Why Ethereum not accessible by default in smartphone?

Tags: dapp-development, dapps, web3-providers, dapp-design, adoption

Before I create a decentralized application, I want to know whether it already exists. I thought the first step would be to search the Google Play Store, but it appears dapps are not available on the Google Play Store, that [users must install additional software and search within that software instead](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18461/how-can-dapps-work-on-smartphones/18708). Why are dapps not available in the Google Play Store? How is the Ethereum network not directly accessible to smartphone users like the Internet network?

Are these questions answered in [State of the Dapps' recommended reading](https://dappdaily.com/ethereum-reading-list-for-prospective-dapp-developers-15d515383b23)?

Comment: Our wallet for Android is coming in October.

Comment: There are already several ethereum wallets, status.im, toshi, cipher, etc. One problem is that if you are a dapp developer you do not want to reimplement wallet and currently there's no service to share a wallet implementation with other applications in android (ie something similar to Metamask in the browser).

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing inherently preventing a Dapp from being run on Android. Ethereum is accessible to Android via Web3, similar to how it is done through a browser(Metamask).

Web3 is accessible to android right now through [Web3j](https://github.com/web3j/web3j).

All android wallets are Dapps as well.

Answer (score 0):

DApps interact directly with blockchain networks (e.g., Ethereum), and they require a blockchain node to function. Mobile devices do not run blockchain nodes by default.  Therefore, users need specialized wallet apps or browsers that provide access to the blockchain. And, the Ethereum network itself is not directly accessible to smartphone users like the Internet because it operates on a peer-to-peer basis, and accessing it requires specialized software (wallets and browsers) that can communicate with the Ethereum network. These wallets and browsers act as the gateway between the traditional Internet and the Ethereum blockchain.